# Value range query for non numerical or alphabetic db values

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql database with a field called clar with data values: SI2, SI1, VS2, VS1, VVS2, VVS1, IF, FL

This is a scale from lowest: SI2 to highest: FL

I cannot change the data format in the database table, i.e. change the values to numeric values. Eg: SI2 = 1 FL = 8

I am wanting to query the table with the following:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `clar` BETWEEN 'SI2' AND 'FL'
```

To get the range of values between SI2 AND FL.

How on earth can I do this?

Obviously the above query gives me an incorrect data range as it is neither alphabetical nor numeric.

Sample rows:

```
field1  field2  field3  field4  clar    field6
-----------------------------------------------
500569  BR      0.120   E       VS2     0.00
500110  BR      0.120   G       SI2     0.00
500549  BR      0.120   F       SI1     0.00
```

Comment: You want all the values, or the range can change?

Comment: The range can vary, so it could be Vs2 to IF, and I want all the values in between

Comment: Can you show some sample rows from the table?

Comment: Can you modify the table to add a new column with 1 to 8 values?

Comment: I cannot modify the table, I thought about doing that: 1-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly name the values you are looking for

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE `clar` in ('SI2','SI1','VS2','VS1','VVS2','VVS1','IF','FL')
```

Comment: I think he only want to specify range limits

Comment: I can build a Query string based on the range they select so this might work.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
 WHERE FIELD (`clar`, 'SI2','SI1','VS2','VS1','VVS2','VVS1','IF','FL')
       BETWEEN 1 AND 8
```

If you want a different range, you only need to change the numeric values in the `BETWEEN` condition. For instance, to get the rows with scores between `VS2` and `IF`, you specify `BETWEEN 3 and 7`.

Comment: I cannot change the database values or add fields with numeric values

Comment: @grant This is not changing the database, it is just a query

Comment: Ah I see what you mean.

Comment: @sranchez Thanks, your query works well, but I am going to accept the answer below only because it is simpler for me to use to build the query string dynamically. Your answer requires me to build some PHP code to interpret the $_POST values and feedback the numeric values. The answer below does not.